# CKEDITOR: Multiple skins on a single page

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am doing so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('entry-short_text',{
    skin: 'Moono_blue,/ckeditor/Moono_blue/',
});
CKEDITOR.replace('entry-full_text',{
    skin: 'office2013,/ckeditor/office2013/',
});
```

All elements of the set only one skin, which is listed last (ie office2013). Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide the html code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor 4 only allows one skin per page.
The ability to load multiple skins on the same page was removed when they redesigned for v. 4.