# CKeditor 4 skin's editor.css not appending on creating instance on different page

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm creating another instance in different SPA page with different skin but it is not appending the corresponding editor.css file, whereas it is appending skin.js file.

I've already searched for multiple skins ckeditor but i got another stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481246/ckeditor-multiple-skins-on-a-single-page) which is clearly saying we can't use multiple skins.

I've destroyed previous instances as well but no luck. One solution was to use appendStyleSheet with the path of the css skin, but is there any clean solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately skins are registered globally for entire page. So one skin is shared with all instances of editor on page.

What you might try to do is a little hack approach. You can prepare custom skin which will combine few skins inside. Then use [divarea](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea) editor type, which will inheritance css from your main page. Use 2 different div's with different class so your modification should be more specific than native css and overwrite it.